# Проблема с задачей, не могу понять что писать дальше после if

Tags: java

Допустим, есть два игрока. Пользователь вводит с консоли имя первого игрока и количество его очков, далее - имя второго игрока и количество его очков.
Программа должна определить победителя и вывести его имя на консоль, либо вывести "Ничья".

```
package hw1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter player");
        int player = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter point");
        int point = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter player2");
        int player2 = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter point2");
        int point2 = scn.nextInt();
        if
```

Comment: очевидно что `if (point > point2)`

Comment: Гуглить пробовали? [java пример условный оператор](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // создаю переменные
            String player;
            String player2;

            // создаю Scanner
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

            // запрашиваю ввод имени первого игрока
            System.out.println("Enter player");
            player = scn.nextLine();

            // запрашиваю ввод балла первого игрока
            System.out.println("Enter point");
            int point = scn.nextInt();

            // запрашиваю ввод имени второго игрока
            System.out.println("Enter player2");
            scn.nextLine();
            player2 = scn.nextLine();

            // запрашиваю ввод балла второго игрока
            System.out.println("Enter point2");
            int point2 = scn.nextInt();

            //проверяю, кто набрал больше баллов
            if(point > point2){
                System.out.println("игрок " + player + " набрал больше баллов чем " + player2);
            }

            else if(point < point2){
                System.out.println("игрок " + player2 + " набрал больше баллов чем " + player);
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("игроки набрали одинаковое количество баллов");
            }
        }
}
```